# Is there a geometric representation of a complex shape? E.g. a ‘triangle’ defined by complex vectors

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry, volume

Just as how a complex plane is for complex numbers (‘1D’ -> ‘2D’) to allow for easier visual understanding, it seems to follow that there should be one at the next level (‘2D’ -> ‘3D’)?

Perhaps a complex volume?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the theory of quaternions? Read the Wikipedia for quaternions. Quaternions describe 3d space with one real axis and 3 imaginary axes. The imaginary units are $i, j$ and $k$. They satisfy $i^2=j^2=k^2=ijk=-1$.

Comment: Quaternions certainly seem to be the natural extension though I’ve never heard of a ‘polygon’ in quaternion space, so to speak. Is that even a sensible thing to say?